# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have problem with `json` example from http://www.java2blog.com/2015/09/spring-restful-web-services-json-example.html
I think that I did everything right, but if I use Tomcat, in log appear message:

```
lis 11, 2015 5:09:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample/country/2] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springrest'
```

Comment: Please post your configuration

Answer (score 1):

You could try  replacing
 /*
with
 /

Worked  for me.

I know its too late for you, but might help  others who  come in search of same problem

Answer (score 0):

**springrest-servlet.xml**

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">  

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
<context:component-scan base-package="org.arpit.java2blog.controller" />  

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC  
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"  
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >  

<web-app>  
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>  
  <servlet>  
 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>  
 <servlet-class>  
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  
 </servlet-class>  
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>  
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <groupId>com.arpit.java2blog</groupId>  
  <artifactId>SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample</artifactId>  
  <packaging>war</packaging>  
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
  <name>SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample Maven Webapp</name>  
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  
  <dependencies>  
    <dependency>  
      <groupId>junit</groupId>  
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
      <version>3.8.1</version>  
      <scope>test</scope>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
   <version>3.1.0</version>  
  </dependency>  

  <dependency>  
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
   <version>${spring.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>  
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
   <version>${spring.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  
   <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>  
             <version>2.4.1</version>  
        </dependency>  
 </dependencies>  
 <build>  
  <finalName>SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample</finalName>  

  <plugins>  
   <plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>3.1</version>  
    <configuration>  
     <source>${jdk.version}</source>  
     <target>${jdk.version}</target>  
    </configuration>  
   </plugin>  
  </plugins>  

 </build>  
 <properties>  
  <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>  
  <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>  
 </properties>  
</project>
```

**Country.java**

```
package org.arpit.java2blog.bean;  

public class Country{  

 int id;  
 String countryName;   

 public Country(int i, String countryName) {  
  super();  
  this.id = i;  
  this.countryName = countryName;  
 }  
 public int getId() {  
  return id;  
 }  
 public void setId(int id) {  
  this.id = id;  
 }  
 public String getCountryName() {  
  return countryName;  
 }  
 public void setCountryName(String countryName) {  
  this.countryName = countryName;  
 }   

}
```

**CountryController.java**

```
package org.arpit.java2blog.controller;  

import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  

import org.arpit.java2blog.bean.Country;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;  

@RestController  
public class CountryController {  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")  
 public List<Country> getCountries()  
 {  
  List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();  
  listOfCountries=createCountryList();  
  return listOfCountries;  
 }  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/country/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")  
 public Country getCountryById(@PathVariable int id)  
 {  
  List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();  
  listOfCountries=createCountryList();  

  for (Country country: listOfCountries) {  
   if(country.getId()==id)  
    return country;  
  }  

  return null;  
 }  

// Utiliy method to create country list.  
 public List<Country> createCountryList()  
 {  
  Country indiaCountry=new Country(1, "India");  
  Country chinaCountry=new Country(4, "China");  
  Country nepalCountry=new Country(3, "Nepal");  
  Country bhutanCountry=new Country(2, "Bhutan");  

  List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();  
  listOfCountries.add(indiaCountry);  
  listOfCountries.add(chinaCountry);  
  listOfCountries.add(nepalCountry);  
  listOfCountries.add(bhutanCountry);  
  return listOfCountries;  
 }  
}
```

[Eclipse view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOQKr.png)

Answer (score 0):

add init-param tag as below and clear your tomcat and restart it.

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springrest-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```